# why isn't this $http request working?

Tags: angularjs, http, service, module, iife

I have a service declared here:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('ngInterview.api.students')
        .service('StudentsService', StudentsService);

    StudentsService.$inject = ['$http'];
    function StudentsService($http) {

        /**
         * Exposed functions
         */

        this.getName = getName; // This function serves no purpose. It's just here as an example.

        this.getStudents = function() {
            console.log("getting to the getStudents function");
            return $http.get("http://il-resume-api.azurewebsites.net/api/students").then(function(res) {
                console.log("getting data back");
                console.log(res.data);
                return res.data;
            }, function(res) {
                console.log("getting bad data");
                console.log(res);
                return res.data;
            });
        }

        /**
         * Implementations
         */

        function getName() {
            return 'studentsService';
        }
    }
})();
```

For some reason my code only gets to the "getting to the getStudents function" and doesn't respond after that. I've tried setting up a blank project with $http in a controller and it works, it retrieves the data from the endpoint but for some reason this service as part of a module won't. And when I console.log $http, I get a valid object so I don't think it's that.

Comment: Immediately after `console.log("getting to the getStudents function");` you are returning from the function. The additional prints to console will only take place upon completion of the HTTP request. Try invoking the http.get within the body if the function and return the function itself.

Comment: Are you handling `getStudents` as a promise? by returning the `$http` you have to use `then` with your `getStudents` function to expect a result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getStudents` function is returning the `$http.get`. By doing this you are handing a promise to whoever choose to invoke `getStudents` function. If you want to see your logging in action, treat your function accordingly, like this:

**Controller Scope**

```
studentsService.getStudents().then(function() {
   console.log("I expect to see my logs right above this log");
})
```

Comment: But I should still get my console.logs, no matter how the controller handles it, correct? Just to make sure I did put a console.log in the controller's .then statement but I didn't get anything there either. :/

Comment: You should see the logs only when the function has made it promise and brought back whatever it was supposed to. Can you show the controller's logic?